# ios: Google Maps in UIWebView prompts to download Google Maps App

Tags: ios, google-maps, uiwebview

Is there a way to call the maps.google.com urls so that it goes straight to the location without asking the user to download the google maps app? Right now it does one of two things. I either first get a page suggesting a download the app, and I can click a link that takes me on. Or it loads the map, but it's squashed down because it shows two buttons above the map that say "Open in Google Maps app" and "Get the app".